# map[string]interface{} not being parsed correctly since switching to new go mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, hashmap

I'm switching to the new mongo go driver (mongo-go-driver), away from mgo

One of our functions is no longer working despite the decoding method not changing (into a map[string]interface{})

I believe that what is happening is that the returned data is not being handled correctly as a map[string]interface{}

The data ingested is a mongo aggregate query:

```
result = map[query_key:procedure_on_cities query_type:run procedure query_value:map[aggregate:[map[£match:map[Source:Cities]] map[£sort:map[Order:1]]] collection:aggregate_stats db:stats] _id:ObjectID("5c5410fac2a7b1b1beae52bc")]
```

**What we need to do is replace the £ with $** in the aggregation for it to run correctly (we encode $ as £ initially to not run into issues with the $ being interpreted incorrectly when the query is put together on the frontend

Previously with mgo, we simply did this:

```
if returnedQuery, ok := result["query_value"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        queryToRun = replace£With$(returnedQuery)
}
```

But this is no longer working...

So the bit that we are wanting to handle as a map[string]interface to pass into the function is this:

```
query_value:map[aggregate:[map[£match:map[Source:Cities]] map[£sort:map[Order:1]]] map[£sort:map[Order:1]]] collection:aggregate_stats db:stats]
```

We assumed, like with mgo, we could just do the previously mentioned type assertion

In my testing, I isolate the part with the £ that I want to replace:

```
result2 = result["query_value"].(map[string]interface{})
```

Then I want to check to see the datatypes and whether what's in the aggregate is even a map[string]interface{}

```
    for key, value := range result2 {

        fmt.Println("key from result2:", key, " || ", "value from result 2:", value)

        if key == "aggregate" {

            fmt.Println("FOUND AGGREGATE || ", "value:", value, " || type: ", reflect.TypeOf(value))

        }
        if valueMSI, ok := value.([]interface{}); ok {
            fmt.Println("Please, print this", keyMSI)
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't print the last statement. WHY?! This is what result2 is:

```
result2 = map[aggregate:[map[£match:map[Source:Cities]] map[£sort:map[Order:1]]] collection:aggregate_stats db:stats]
```

It is a []interface{} isn't it?! It should be printing that statement since the aggregate key's associated value is an array that contains maps

When performing type checks the response was:

```
primitive.A
```

**Is primitive.A not treated as an []interface{}?**

Comment: Check what type `value` actually is (e.g. `fmt.Printf("%T", value)`).

Comment: Ahh sorry, that was one of the first steps I took... updating the answer (primitive.A)

Comment: @Adrian this is present in the mongo-db-driver documentation - https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive and it says that the underlying type is "type A []interface{}"

Comment: Yep. So you could assert to `[]interface{}`, then assert the items therein to `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: @Adrian in the last part of my loop, I tried asserting to an []interface{} then tried the same ok statement to see if it printed, no luck here. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the new mongo driver uses a primitive.A datatype for []interface{}

primitive.A has the **underlying datatype of []interface{}** but the type literal is primitive.A

To solve the problem you need first do the type assertion for primitive.A then do a conversion to the type literal[]interface{}:

I've imported the package for bson primitive with a name:

```
import (
    bsonNewGoDriverPrimitive "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

if valuePA, ok := value.(bsonNewGoDriverPrimitive.A); ok {
        vI := []interface{}(valuePA)}
```